# How to use the "Find in Path" options in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

There are four "location" options to `Find in Path`:  `Project`, `Module`, `Directory`, and `Scope`.  I would have thought that the most restrictive would be `Directory` but instead it is the only one I am seeing any results:

**Directory**

[image]

The expected results can be seen by doing a search from the command line in the root of the project:

```
$find . -name \*.js | xargs grep "n createSTFT(" 2>/dev/null
./js/cough-app-local-audio-file.js:function createSTFT(buffer) {
./js/testOnsets.js:function createSTFT(buffer) {
./js/cough-local-file.headless.js:export function createSTFT(buffer) {
```

I would expect the remaining types of searches to find *all* of those results - but instead they find .. *nothing* ??

**Project**

[image]

**Module**

[image]

**All Places**

[image]

So the only one that makes any sense is `Directory` .. but even that one is missing results.. What are these options supposed to do and why are they not showing the expected results?  I am on `Intellij 2019.3.5 Ultimate`

Comment: Not possible unless the directory in which you are searching is not part of the IntelliJ project.  Keep in mind that just because you view this file and directory as logically being part of the project, it does not mean IntelliJ sees it the same way.

Comment: Do these folders belong to the module content roots? See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html.

Comment: @CrazyCoder  You are on the right track . I went to try to `Mark Directory as Source` but not available - only `Load Path root` .  I do not understand what is going on with this Project.

Comment: You've imported it as a web project instead of the Java project. Web projects do not have the source roots, only content roots.

Comment: Oh that's interesting - OK i'll re-import the project: there is R code as well so web project will not be optimal.  Can you make this an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure it's the right answer since find in path should work within the module content roots, not only the source roots.

Comment: It's working now with re-importing.  Your answer would likely be helpful to others that like me somehow imported as Web Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the module was imported with the right type and has the content and/or source roots configured properly. Find in Path will work within the module roots only when you have specified the option to search in a project or in a module.

You can remove the module and [add a new one](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#add-new-module) or [adjust the roots configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html).

Comment: In particular: it seems I somehow imported this as `Web Project`. I did as @CrazyCoder said - that is reimport it and the `Find in Path` are all working as expected now.